# How to separate tableview header and cellForRowAt from same json in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, uitableview

I want to display countrycode as header of table view and after click on header venue should display. I had tried but I'm unable to achieve output as expected.

**This is my json :**

```
{
  "meetings": [
    {
      "meetingId": 31389393,
      "name": "Ludlow 20th Apr",
      "openDate": "2022-04-20T12:00:00+00:00",
      "venue": "Ludlow",
      "eventTypeId": 7,
      "countryCode": "GB",
      "meetingGoing": "Good"
    },
    {
      "meetingId": 31389469,
      "name": "Catterick 20th Apr",
      "openDate": "2022-04-20T12:40:00+00:00",
      "venue": "Catterick",
      "eventTypeId": 7,
      "countryCode": "GB",
      "meetingGoing": "Good (Good to Soft in places)"
    },
    {
      "meetingId": 31389416,
      "name": "Perth 20th Apr",
      "openDate": "2022-04-20T12:50:00+00:00",
      "venue": "Perth",
      "eventTypeId": 7,
      "countryCode": "GB",
      "meetingGoing": "Good to Soft (Good in places)"
    },
    {
      "meetingId": 31389532,
      "name": "Lingfield 20th Apr",
      "openDate": "2022-04-20T15:15:00+00:00",
      "venue": "Lingfield",
      "eventTypeId": 7,
      "countryCode": "GB",
      "meetingGoing": "Standard"
    },
    {
      "meetingId": 31389447,
      "name": "Salisbury 20th Apr",
      "openDate": "2022-04-20T15:25:00+00:00",
      "venue": "Salisbury",
      "eventTypeId": 7,
      "countryCode": "GB",
      "meetingGoing": "Good to Firm (Good in places)"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Here is my code which is I'm using for getting data:**

```
    struct Racing{
        var countryCode:String
        var venue: [String]
        var races: [Races]?
    }
    
    var todayRacingArray = [Racing]()
    APIClient2<RacingListBaseClass>().API_GET(Url: url, Params: noParams, Authentication: false, Progress: false, Alert: true, Offline: false, SuperVC: self, completionSuccess: { (response) in
    for item in response.meetings ?? []
    {
       let cc = item.countryCode
       var venue = [String]()
       ven.append(item.venue ?? "")
       let obj = Racing(countryCode: cc ?? "", venue: venue)
       self.todayRacingArray.append(obj)
    }
    self.otherSportsTableView.reloadData()
 }) { (failed) in
            
        }
```

**TableView:**

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.todayRacingArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int     {
    return self.todayRacingArray[section].venue.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: HeaderTableViewCell.self)) as! HeaderTableViewCell
    let obj = todayRacingArray[section]
    cell.titleLbl.text = obj.countryCode
    return cell
  }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: BodyTableViewCell.self)) as! BodyTableViewCell
    cell.frame = tableView.bounds
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    let obj = self.todayRacingArray[indexPath.section].venue[indexPath.row]
    cell.horseTitleLabel.text = obj
    return cell
}
```

**My Output** [My table Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGIu0.jpg) [After Clicking on header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2Jqm.jpg)
**I want Output like this:** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3FLM.jpg) [After clicking on header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVp6R.jpg)

Please someone helpme out with this.

Comment: You are trying to access ```var venue: [String]``` as array but in json file it's a string.

Comment: yes I want that strings in array

Comment: please share the code of ```Meeting``` model e.g. ```response.meetings```. In every Meeting model their is a ```venue``` and ```countryCode```.

Comment: Yes there is Venue and countryside is every meeting model.

  **public var eventTypeId: Int?    public var name: String?
  public var races: [Races]?
  public var countryCode: String?
  public var meetingGoing: String?
  public var venue: String?
  public var meetingId: Int?
  public var openDate: String?**

Comment: what is the defination of ```Races``` model? ```public var races: [Races]?```

Comment: races is another array inside json which is not require

Comment: In ```Meeting``` model you have defined all the properties as optional. Nothing of them is not required like ```venue``` and ```countryCode```?

Comment: yes I have remove that properties which is not require

Comment: You don't need to remove optional properties. If you know that some of the properties those you will always get from API then declare them as non optional like ```var countryCode: String```. Just remove the ```?```.

Comment: Okay removed the optional

Comment: I have updated the answer. please check @Aryan Vishwakarma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Updated Answer***

Add a new model `RaceVenue`. Then modify `Racing` struct like below.

```
struct RaceVanue {
    var venue: String
    var races: [Race]?
}

struct Racing {
    var countryCode:String
    var raceVenues: [RaceVanue]
}
```

Modify the declaration of `countryVenueDict` dictionary.

```
var countryVenueDict: [String: [RaceVanue]] = [:]
```

Then modify the code when adding it to `countryVenueDict` dictionary. And then also modify Racing model when add it to `todayRacingArray`

```
for item in response.meetings ?? []
{
    if let _ = countryVenueDict[item.countryCode ?? ""] {
        countryVenueDict[item.countryCode ?? ""]?.append(RaceVanue(venue: item.venue ?? "", races: item.races))
    } else {
        countryVenueDict[item.countryCode ?? ""] = [RaceVanue(venue: item.venue ?? "", races: item.races)]
    }
}

todayRacingArray += countryVenueDict.map { Racing(countryCode: $0.key, raceVenues: $0.value) }
```

***Previous Answer***

Add a dictionary to map the `venue` with `countrycode` before the declaration of `todayRacingArray`

```
var countryVenueDict: [String: [String]] = [:]
var todayRacingArray = [Racing]()
```

Modify the code in for loop like below.

```
for item in response.meetings ?? []
{
    if let _ = countryVenueDict[item.countryCode ?? ""] {
        countryVenueDict[item.countryCode ?? ""]?.append(item.venue ?? "")
    } else {
        countryVenueDict[item.countryCode ?? ""] = [item.venue ?? ""]
    }
}
```

Then append [Racing] array to `todayRacingArray` by mapping the transforming the `countryVenueDict` by using map function.

```
todayRacingArray += countryVenueDict.map { Racing(countryCode: $0.key, venue: $0.value) }
```

Here is the full code

```
var countryVenueDict: [String: [String]] = [:]
var todayRacingArray = [Racing]()
APIClient2<RacingListBaseClass>().API_GET(Url: url, Params: noParams, Authentication: false, Progress: false, Alert: true, Offline: false, SuperVC: self, completionSuccess: { (response) in
    for item in response.meetings ?? []
    {
        if let _ = countryVenueDict[item.countryCode ?? ""] {
            countryVenueDict[item.countryCode ?? ""]?.append(item.venue ?? "")
        } else {
            countryVenueDict[item.countryCode ?? ""] = [item.venue ?? ""]
        }
    }
    todayRacingArray += countryVenueDict.map { Racing(countryCode: $0.key, venue: $0.value) }
    self.otherSportsTableView.reloadData()
}) { (failed) in
    
}
```

Comment: Don't you get different ```countryCode``` in the same API? If you have to call API multiple times to get data related to different ```countryCode``` then this problem happens. Could you please confirm? I will modify the code accordingly.

Comment: I got it I'm getting second country code in different api with same json response..I want to merge both api data in single array which is todayRacingArray.

Comment: if I want to access races array within same code how can I do?
here is the json with races array

Comment: {
  "meetings": [
    {
      "races": [
        {
          "inplay": false,
          "status": "OPEN"
        },
        {
          "inplay": false,
          "status": "OPEN"
        }
      ],
      "meetingId": 31391947,
      "venue": "Perth",
      "countryCode": "GB"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: I have updated my answer. Now you can get all data in ```todayRacingArray``` comes from different api.

Comment: To achieve this  add ```var races: [Races]?``` property to ```Racing``` model. Then store it to the dictionary when fetching data and then add it to the array.

Comment: after merging the data from both api now in venue gets replicated for eg if I have two "GB" cell in first one showing first api venues as well as second api venue and  in second cell of"GB" shows second api venue.It should be first api venue goes in first "GB" cell and second one in second"GB"cell.

Comment: Move ```var countryVenueDict: [String: [RaceVanue]] = [:]``` inside API method just after the beginning curly brace  and check.

Comment: How can I add one more property in Racing struct i.e var status:String

Comment: You don't need to. ```Racing``` struct already has a property ```var raceVenues: [RaceVanue]``` and ```RaceVenue``` struct has property ```var races: [Race]?```. You can access ```status``` by calling like ```racingItem.raceVenues[0].races[0].status``` .

Comment: no this status is different and its need with countrycode

Comment: It's simple. Add the property to Racing struct. ```struct Racing {var countryCode:String var raceVenues: [RaceVanue] var status: String}```. Then modify everywhere you initialize a ```Racing``` object.